# Angular 10,router-outlet output with EventEmitter to parent in SideNav Content

Tags: angular, angular10

I've a Layout Page that mat-sidenav-container and router-outlet in it.I try to call the function and pass data to LayoutPage from router-outlet Page By EventEmitter but it's not working.
I found the similar problem with me here:
[@Output with EventEmitter from child to parent, view doesn't update in parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48489723/output-with-eventemitter-from-child-to-parent-view-doesnt-update-in-parent)

And it's work if replacing router-outlet tag to component selector tag (app-child),but router-outlet tag is necessary for me.I need to navigate the webPage By router-outlet tag.How could I do then?

**layout.component.html**

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav #sideNav opened="true" mode="side" class="sidebar" style="background-image: url('assets/images/test.png');">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" class="test nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]" [queryParams]="filter">
                <i class="material-icons">{{menuItem.icon}}</i>
                <p>{{menuItem.title}}</p>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </mat-sidenav>
  
    <mat-sidenav-content class="content">
        <app-header></app-header>
      <router-outlet (onDatePicked)='doSomething($event)' > </router-outlet>
      
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
```

**layout.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  templateUrl: './layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./layout.component.css']
})
export class ChemoLayoutComponent implements OnInit {

  filter:Filter
  menuItems: any[];
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,private app: ApplicationRef) {
    this.menuItems = [
      { path: '/chemo/child', title: 'aaa',  icon: 'library_books' },
      { path: '/chemo/child1', title: 'bbb',  icon:'build'},
      { path: '/chemo/child2', title: 'ccc',  icon:'search' },
  ];
  this.filter = new Filter();
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
      this.filter.CHARTNO = params['CHARTNO'];
    });
  }

  doSomething($event){  //<== It's not working
    this.app.tick();
    console.log("Test");
  }
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() onDatePicked: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  constructor() {

   }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.onDatePicked.emit("hello");
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<router-outlet (onDatePicked)='doSomething($event)' > </router-outlet>`

This will not work because `onDatePicked` output does not exist on `RouterOutlet` (cf. [Angular doc](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet)).

If you want to communicate from child to parent component without being limited by routing, you need to implement a service. It can look like this :

**child-to-parent.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChildToParentService {

  onDatePicked$ = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() { }

}
```

**layout.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  templateUrl: './layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./layout.component.css']
})
export class ChemoLayoutComponent implements OnDestroy {

  onDatePickedSub: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private childToParentService: ChildToParentService
  ) {
    this.onDatePickedSub = this.childToParentService.onDatePicked$.subscribe($event => {
      this.doSomething($event);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.onDatePickedSub) {
      this.onDatePickedSub.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  doSomething($event): void {
    this.app.tick();
    console.log("Test");
  }

}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private childToParentService: ChildToParentService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.childToParentService.onDatePicked$.next('hello');
  }

}
```