# Angular 11, is it possible to pass content of ActivatedRoute data from child object to parent?

Tags: angular, angular11

Let's say my parent looks like this:

```
<div class="container pt-4">
    <div class="[...]">
    <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

The router is defined as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'books', 
    component: BooksComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Book List'
    }
  },
  { 
    path: '', 
    redirectTo: 'books', 
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

When I fetch the data content in child, I see 'Book List', so this works:

```
export class BooksComponent implements OnInit, ComponentData {

  title: string = '';

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.title = data['title'];
      console.log('data=', this.title);
    });
  }
}
```

But as you can see, I want to display `{{ title }}` in the parent view, so anyhow I need to pass the data to the parent. When I use the code of ngOnInit() in the parent component to fetch the title from data, then the value is undefined. What is the proper way to pass the data back to the parent? Is using an EventEmitter the proper way to do this or can this be done in a different way? I'm not sure what's the proper design pattern for this but I guess this is a common use case to display child related route data content in the parent view.

Comment: Do you think about using variable in service?

Comment: I suggest reading, the following blogs.
https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/5-ways-to-share-data-between-angular-components-d656a7eb7f96

or this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65105105/angular-10-router-outlet-output-with-eventemitter-to-parent-in-sidenav-content

I think the way forward for you is using a common service, in which you update the variable in the `child component`, and listen to it in the `parent component`